# Proof using Taylor's theorem

Tags: taylor-expansion

Use Taylor's theorem to prove that $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} n \ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)=1$

I don't understand how to apply Taylor's theorem to a limit, especially one with a product of two functions...

Comment: try using taylor series expansion for $\ln (1+x)$

Comment: Ok, I understand this, but how do I multiply it by n and take the limit?

Comment: see that the limit exists .. $\frac{1}{n+1}< \ln (1+\frac{1}{n})< \frac{1}{n}$, we are only applying the Taylor series to evaluate the limit at the point :)

Comment: Duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/q/698331/18398

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche It is a duplicate, but this is the original version of the question. The other version has four votes for closure already, so it should be marked as duplicate soon.

Answer (score 1):

As $\displaystyle n\to\infty,\frac1n\to0\implies \left|\frac1n\right|<1$

Using $\#19$ of  [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SeriesExpansion.html) , $$\ln\left(1+\frac1n\right)=\frac1n-\frac1{n^2}+\frac1{n^3}-\cdots$$

Comment: Ok, I understand this, but how do I multiply it by n and take the limit?

Comment: @kiwifruit, $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac nn=?$$ and $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac n{n^k}=?$$ for integer $k>1$

Comment: Is it correct that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n}{n^k} = \frac {lim_{n \to \infty} n}{lim_{n \to \infty} n^k}?$

Comment: @kiwifruit No. Since $\lim_{n\to\infty} n$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} n^k$ are not converge, so you do not apply the theorem $\lim_n a_nb_n = \lim a_n \cdot \lim b_n$.

Answer (score 0):

By Taylor's theorem, we have $$\ln(1+t) = t + o(t)$$ as $t \to 0$. Substituting $t = \frac{1}{n}$, we get, as $n \to \infty$, $$\ln(1 + \frac{1}{n}) = \frac{1}{n} + o(\frac{1}{n})$$

Thus, we have $$n \ln(1 + \frac{1}{n}) = n \left[\frac{1}{n} + o(\frac{1}{n})\right] = 1 + n \cdot o(\frac{1}{n}) = 1 + \frac{o(\frac{1}{n})}{\frac{1}{n}} \to 1 + 0 = 1$$ as $n \to \infty$

Answer (score 0):

Recall that 
$$
\ln(1+x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^{k+1}\frac{x^k}{k}
$$
for $|x|<1$. Then
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}n\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}n\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^{k+1}\frac{1}{n^k k} \\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^{k+1}\frac{1}{n^{k-1} k} \\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left\{1+\sum_{k=2}^\infty(-1)^{k+1}\frac{1}{n^{k-1} k}\right\} \\
&=1+\sum_{k=2}^\infty(-1)^{k+1}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n^{k-1} k} \\
&= 1
\end{align*}